# How can I run code, that will call the class extended AsyncTask, under UI Thread in Unit testing class in Android Testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing

First, let me give you the scenario:

```
interface TaskDone{

 void OnTaskDone(Object data)

}


public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void, Bitmap>{

    private TaskDone callback;
    public DownloadImage(TaskDone callback){this.callback=callback}
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String ...params){

        Bitmap image= null;
       // contact to server and download image

        return image;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null) {
                callback.onTaskDone(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to do Unit test that the image is being downloaded. As it is mandatory that the DownloadImage class needs to be called from UI thread and I don't have any Activity class in my source packages. How can I write unit testing for DownloadImage class? I have done something like the following but it seems to me that runOnUIThread is not running.

```
class DownloadImageTest {

    @Before
     public void setUp() throws Exception {

            countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    }

    public void test1_TaskDownload_should_download_a_lanscape_banner() throws Throwable {

        Context context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);

        Context contextSpy = PowerMockito.spy(context);

        Intent intent = new Intent(contextSpy, Activity.class);

        contextSpy.startActivity(intent);

        activity.startActivity(intent);

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DownloadImage downloadImage = new DownloadImage(new TaskDone() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTaskDone(Object data) {            
                            rawImageLandscape = (Bitmap) data;
                            countDownLatch.countDown();
                        }
                    });
                    downloadImage.execute(URL);
                }
        });


        try {

              countDownLatch.await(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading the question too.`enter code here`

Comment: yes there is no thread called UI thread when you run unit tests, in order to have access to UI thread you need to write a instrumentation test

Comment: Thank you SparK for nicely formatting. Thank you Bhargav for your comment. Anyway, I did the same thing in instrumentation test where I extended ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 class. But it wouldn't give me any result rather it expects one Activity. Moreover, DownloadImage has no relation with any Activity or UI. Any related link or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You know why `AsyncTasks` expect  to be started from UI thread? its because after doInBackground it can run the `postExecute` method in the UI thread to update UI elements with the result from `doInBackground` , this is the purpose of AsyncTasks an Api to easily offload work to background thread and update UI from the background thread

Comment: btw have you checked if doInBackground and onPostExecute get executed by debugging?

Comment: You really need to learn how to post code here

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.